# tf.image.resize and and cv2.resize: are they supposed to be the same or different?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

There's an infamous [post](https://hackernoon.com/how-tensorflows-tf-image-resize-stole-60-days-of-my-life-aba5eb093f35) about bugs in `tf.image.resize`. Now we have `tf 2.0` but I still just can't get the same results with this function that I can easily get with `ImageDataGenerator`.

So is this method supposed to be the same as in `pillow` and `cv2` or not? See details [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cufzcjbcjceF03CV03YdElPgvHELuBXD?usp=sharing).

```
# we may get the same image
image_tf = tf.io.read_file(str(image_path))
image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_tf, channels=3, dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE')

image_cv = cv2.imread(str(image_path))
image_cv = cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

np.sum(np.abs(image_cv - image_tf)) # 0

# but not the same resized image
image_tf_res = tf.image.resize(image_tf, IMAGE_SIZE, method='bilinear')
image_cv_res = cv2.resize(image_cv, tuple(IMAGE_SIZE), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# this is NOT 0
np.sum(np.abs(image_cv_res - image_tf_res))
```

Comment: what kind of answer are you hoping to get from this? this seems to be a question that should be asked to the developers themselves

Comment: It looks like we still have a different behavior at least between pillow and tf with resize function in 2023... isn't it ?